# Postgres 9.3 slow aggregation

Tags: performance, postgresql-9.3

Once more a performance-tuning question:

The query

```
select 
    ipc_class_symbol,count ( tls201_appln.appln_id)
from
    tls201_appln,
    tls209_appln_ipc
where
    tls201_appln.appln_id=tls209_appln_ipc.appln_id
group by 
    tls209_appln_ipc.ipc_class_symbol
```

is executed with plan

```
    "HashAggregate  (cost=9767241.49..9767481.92 rows=24043 width=16) (actual time=422312.135..422355.589 rows=72506 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=992580"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=132.89..8764451.97 rows=200557904 width=16) (actual time=0.068..234936.829 rows=200557856 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: (tls201_appln.appln_id = tls209_appln_ipc.appln_id)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=992580"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using appln_id_idx on tls201_appln  (cost=0.57..1673775.53 rows=81711664 width=4) (actual time=0.033..26993.348 rows=72642821 loops=1)"
"              Heap Fetches: 0"
"              Buffers: shared hit=198493"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using tls209_appln_ipc_keyidx on tls209_appln_ipc  (cost=0.57..4604685.13 rows=200557904 width=16) (actual time=0.023..79085.426 rows=200557856 loops=1)"
"              Heap Fetches: 0"
"              Buffers: shared hit=794087"
"Total runtime: 422366.717 ms"
```

and duration

```
Total query runtime: 358032 ms.
72506 rows retrieved.
```

From my understanding and reading here I assume that the plan is somewhat optimal.

The machine is 64GB, 8 core,dedicated win64bit server. index tables are on SSD, table on spinning.

`postgresql.conf` is tuned to values I found here (page costs, mem etc.).

The problem is now, that the same query returns in ~18 seconds on a similar machine with SQL Server DBMS.

(I want to have PostgreSQL for the production system, because I think in the long run we will be way better off with transparency and understanding than heuristics and intransparency)

My last guess is, that there might some relation to underlying performance primitives/libraries (sadly I cannot compare to a different OS).

So any hints/comments/suggestions on how to reduce execution time would most highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `explain analyze` so that we can see _where_ the time is lost. Large aggregations are unfortunately not the strongest part of Postgres. However I had a similar issue and tested the upcoming version 9.5 which has some significant improvements in that area. My test query dropped down from 40 seconds to about 15 seconds (which is about the same time it took that query to run on Oracle). 9.4 might already be faster than 9.3

Comment: Sorry, edited. Ok - I might wait for 9.5 release then.

Comment: You can already try the 9.5 beta if you want: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name These days it's worth asking for `explain (buffers, analyze)` to show cache hits

Comment: @Felix, this could be a case where PostgreSQL's lack of parallelism really hurts. Some parallel query support has been committed to 9.6, but that's a while off.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks for your hints. I added the explain (buffers, analyze) output above, but I do not understand it - should they in the approach the number of rows in the join result best case? What astonishes me, that the join is so fast in comparison to the to hash-counting. As I said, I sadly don't have a unix system at hand to test. Could it have something to do with the hash table libraries under windows? Do you know which pg uses, or is it internal to pg?

Comment: settings: work_mem = 512MB; shared_buffers = 16GB, #temp_buffers = 8MB (default?), #bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100, #wal_buffers = -1

Comment: It might not be parallelism: When I add a second attribute in GROUP, exec-time non-linearly increases to way more than one hour, (SQLserver stays within ~20 sec), making me assume it might be an algorithmic cause?

Comment: @Felix The hash support is internal to Pg. What plan does MS SQL Server use? Looks like the query is probably CPU-bound, since it's getting all cache hits. Check your system performance monitor. Remember that Pg can use at most 100% of *one core*. It'd be interesting to test this on 9.5 and, if it still performs similarly, profile it. For that you'd probably have to be able to share the dataset, especially as not many experienced PostgreSQL devs also know Windows well.

Comment: @ Craig CPU is ~60% for one CPU, working set mem allocated by pg.exe is ~12GB, I will get back on the SQLserver plan, because I don't have rights on that machine.

Comment: I will test the 9.5 however that will take some time, since Im not that fluid in upgrading yet.

Answer (score 0):

Index  tls209_appln_ipc.ipc_class_symbol and you should gain some speed out of it.

Comment: it is: CREATE INDEX ipc_sym_idx
  ON tls209_appln_ipc
  USING btree
  (ipc_class_symbol COLLATE pg_catalog."POSIX" varchar_pattern_ops)
TABLESPACE patstat_index;